# Does Python come with a function to split a list using a delimiter?

Tags: python

Having a `list` that contains `string`s, I want to split the `list` at each point where it contains the empty `string` (`''`), e.g.

```
['this', 'is', '', 'an', 'example']
```

should become

```
[['this', 'is'], ['an', 'example']]
```

I wrote a generator that does this:

```
def split(it, delimiter):
    it = iter(it)
    buffer = []
    while True:
        element = next(it)
        if element != delimiter:
            buffer.append(element)
        elif buffer:
            yield buffer
            buffer = []
```

Since this looks pretty general, I was wondering if I missed some similar function or related pattern in `itertools` or somewhere else...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> words = ['this', 'is', '', 'an', 'example']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(words, ''.__ne__) if k]
[['this', 'is'], ['an', 'example']]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(words, 'is'.__ne__) if k]
[['this'], ['', 'an', 'example']]
```

Comment: I think I would use a lambda function here rather than `''.__ne__`, but the idea is the same and this does the trick nicely.  +1.

Comment: How to understand `k` in this context?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien `''.__ne__`, checks if each item is not equal to `''` if `k` is `True`, then the item was unequal to `''`,so use it, if `k` is `False`,  then the item was `equal` to `''` so it skips it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply [slice the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation), all you have to do is find the index of delimiter.